# How to create a device file and simulate behaviors of the Pseudo-devices?

Tags: python, devices, c

I am trying to create a device that accept input and generate special output.

To make it simple, say I want to create a device which accepts any input (like `/dev/zero`) and writes `00 ff 00 ff 00 ff` ... whenever read by another program.

Is it possible and easy to be achieved in C or in Python?

Comment: If you are happy with just one direction, you can use a named pipe, with a simple C or Python program at the other end.

Comment: @dirkt Named pipe does not seem to work. First, it cannot be read and written at the same time. Second, when multiple programs reads it, the data would go to each program randomly, instead of the behaviour like `/dev/zero`